# Angular form works on Chrome, Opera, IE, but fails on FireFox & Safari

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Angular form that works on some browsers but silently fails on others. As the subject says, the form works in Chrome, Opera and IE, and fails in Safari and FireFox.

When it works I can track the success in debug mode by putting a break point on the POST method of the REST api. When it fails that break point never gets hit.

My button is:

```
<button class="extraSpace" type="submit" value="Send" (click)="onProcessForm()">Send</button>
```

I see the same failure whether I have `type="button"` or `type="submit"`.

Here is the `onProcessForm()` method:

```
  onProcessForm() {
    this.alumniService.postAlumnus(this.surveyFormData).then(()=>null);
    window.location.href="http://www.law.unc.edu/alumni/outreach/thankyou.aspx";
  }
```

When watching the network traffic in the various browser based tools or in WireShark, if things are going to work, I see a POST packet, but if they are going to fail I never see the POST.

I can post the POST method from my REST api but I'm skipping it for now since it works anytime it is hit, but obviously cannot do anything if it does not get called.

Bottom line: what can I do to make this form work in FireFox an Safari (without breaking it's behavior in Chrome, Opera and IE)?

Comment: why are you posting a form and redirecting at the same time... It is a race condition.

Comment: This is a legacy form that I did not write but have to get working. Form your comment, I'm guessing that you think I should get rid of either the type="submit" or the value="send"? If not, please clarify.

Comment: What version of Firefox and Safari?

Comment: Windows 10: FireFox 56.0.1; Mac OS (10.12.6) FireFox 56.0, Safari 11.0 (12604.38.1.7)